# How can digital projectors play 35mm movies?

Tags: production, distribution

Here I saw a [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/68751/why-are-movies-still-shot-in-35mm) with a user claiming that so many movies are still shot with 35MM analog film.

Now if projectors at theaters became digital then how can digital projectors play these 35mm movies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What stock a movie is shot on doesn't mean it can't be digitized and shown on a digital projector.

I'll quote from a link this [**canonical answer**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34435/was-film-actually-better-than-digital-media)

> To get your film onto video for editing you will need to do a film to digital transfer. However I generally prefer to do a supervised transfer on the off days of a shoot. This costs a little more but insures that everything looks the way I intended it and is usually cheaper in the long run because you never need to transfer again. **Supervised transfer is billed by the hour so the cost is the same for 16mm and 35mm**.
>
> You can transfer to HD 720P, 1080I, or 1080P at most facilities. 2k, 4k or even higher resolution film scans are available at some postproduction houses [snip]. You can transfer to tape or directly to your hard drive. *Discounts are available especially if you are doing a feature and need over 10 hours*.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://www.matthewwagenknecht.com/the-actual-costs-of-film/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Movies that are shot on film (photochemically processed) as they have always been since movies were invented for over 100 years, are developed. Then either the original camera negative or the print is scanned and digitized and stored as a file. Before the use of digital projection, this process was used to manipulate the look of the film, called digital intermediate (DI) and then printed back onto 35mm film. Now that theatrical film projection is almost exclusively all digital,  a movie whether originated on film or shot directly using a digital camera is mastered, distributed and shown via digital means. This file is formatted for distribution to theaters. The movie is transmitted via internet or satellite, or sometimes shipped on a hard-drive, and stored on a server in the theater. A typical projector used is a DLP (Digital Light Processing) type of either 2K or 4K resolution.